# Vue.js Components data not showing in vite laravel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Vue.js Components data not showing in vite Laravel after importing it inside App.js. Components are showing in console as shown in image
[image]

App.js

```
<script>
       import MyComponents from 
  "../js/components/MyComponents.vue";
       import Component2 from "./components/Component2.vue";
     
</script>
<template>
    
        <MyComponents/>
        <Component2/>
    <h1>
       view  App Components
    </h1>
</template>
```

MyComponent

```
<template>
    <h1>What's up!</h1>
    sadsadsadasdas
    <Component2/>
  </template>

  <script>
   import Component2 from './Component2.vue';
</script>
```

Component2

```
<template>
      
      dfsfdsf

</template>
```

Vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    vue({
        template: {
          compilerOptions: {
            isCustomElement: (tag) => 
 ['MyComponents','Component2'].includes(tag),
          }
        },
        transformAssetUrls: {
            base: null,
            includeAbsolute: false,
        },
      }),
    laravel({
        input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
        refresh: true,
    }),
],
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@': '/resources/js',
        'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
    },
  },
});
```

I tried to import components as given in the vue.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you should use `script setup` (if your intention is to proceed with the Composition API).

```
  <script setup>
   import Component2 from './Component2.vue';
  </script>
```

Otherwise, include your imports inside `components` section, as per [vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html).

```
<script>
 import Component2 from './Component2.vue';

 export default {
  components: {
   Component2 
  }
 }
</script>
```